# Magento 2 - Show modal if no quote shipping address

Tags: magento2, addtocart, quote, mixins

I am trying to alert the user that they have not added a postcode into their session when clicking "Add to cart"

I have created a mixin, "catalog-add-to-cart-mixin.js" within my custom module.

The issue that I am having is the variable "quote" is `undefined`.

How can I pass through the `Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote` shipping address to the `submitForm` function to be able to see if there is a postcode or not?

Here is my code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function($, $t, ui, quote, modal) {
    "use strict";

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.catalogAddToCart', widget, {
            submitForm: function (quote, form) {
                alert("there");
                var postcode = quote.shippingAddress().postcode;

                console.log(postcode);

                debugger;

                if(!quote.shippingAddress()) {
                    this.showModal(form);
                } else {
                    this.ajaxSubmit(form);
                }
            },


            showModal: function(form) {
                console.log('show modal');
                $('#shipping-popup-modal').modal('openModal');
            }

        });

        return $.mage.catalogAddToCart;
    }
});
```

I am open to options.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it was this block

```
<referenceBlock name=""checkout.cart.shipping"" remove=""true""/>
```

I removed that line and I overwrote shipping.phtml on my theme to remove the shipping address and to keep the checkoutConfig and the JavaScript